# Environment Variables and Shell Rc File

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, amazon-s3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

I am trying to automatically establish a connection with Amazon s3 using keys. [This](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/) documentation provides instructions but I am unsure of how to set environment variables and where my shell rc file is located.

Using linux, how do I set environment variables and what/where is a shell rc file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on which shell your using. I'm going to assume you'll be using bash. To set an environment variable:

```
VARNAME=new_value_of_variable
export VARNAME
```

If you want the changes to be persistent you should add these commands to the file `$HOME/.bash_profile`

For bash the rc file is `$HOME/.bashrc`

You can find out which shell you are using with the command `echo $SHELL`. If you are using something other than bash I can update this for whatever shell you're using